# Visual Studio crashes, faulting module msvcr80.dll

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, webkit, windows-xp, visual-studio-express

I'm trying to compile [WebKit](http://www.webkit.org/building/tools.html) on Windows XP.  I've followed to the letter the installation instructions for all the recommended development tools.  The WebKit project suggests debugging using Visual-Studio 2005.

Whenever I open the WebKit project in VS2005 (express), however, VS always crashes shortly afterward.  This is before I try to run any of the WebKit code, so I think the problem is with VS2005, and not with WebKit.

The error log says this:

> Faulting application vcexpress.exe, version 8.0.50727.762, faulting
>   module msvcr80.dll, version 8.0.50727.6195, fault address 0x00008aa0.

So it looks like the problem is with msvcr80.dll.

I'm not very experienced with windows. Does anyone know how to investigate the cause of this crash and fix it?

Many, many thanks,

D

*** UPDATE ***

In the end I couldn't get VS2005 to stop crashing, so I switched to Visual Studio 2008 Express.  [WebKit.org](http://www.webkit.org/) doesn't give instructions for building with VS2008, but I found some on [this blog](http://blog.ashodnakashian.com/2011/09/building-webkit-on-windows/).  These mostly worked, though I had to make two small changes.

1. Currently, if no standard editions Visual Studio can be found (not 'Express'), the build scripts are hard-coded to use VS Express 2005.  To use VS Express 2008 instead, I changed line 1419 of /Tools/Scripts/webkitdirs.pm from this:

   $vsInstallDir = File::Spec->catdir($programFilesPath, "Microsoft Visual Studio 8");

to this:

```
$vsInstallDir = File::Spec->catdir($programFilesPath, "Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0");
```

(Carefully not to confuse the years of release --2005, 2008-- with the versions -- 8,9.0)

1. I also had to work around a bug related to error logging.  In line 60 of /Tools/Scripts/print-vse-error-logs I changed "scm.find_checkout_root()" to the path to my source directory "C:/cygwin//Webkit/Source".

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the lastest service pack installed on both XP and Visual Studio 2005? if not ([How to obtain the latest Visual Studio 2005 service pack](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929697)). If that doesn't fix it, trying doing the same thing with Visual Studio 2010 (SP1), for it may have been fixed since then and you could be running into known issues which have since been resolved.

HTH

Comment: Yes, I've installed all the latest service packs for both VS and XP. I'm reluctant to use a version of VS later than 2005 because the webkit project people say that later versions aren't "supported". If I can't find another fix, though, I'd definitely try VS2010 as a last resort.

Comment: The other option is to try the development on a different operating system say Windows 7 instead of XP...HTH